# How does hadoop / YARN decide that a node is slow and what does it do with the tasks on it?

Tags: performance, hadoop, nodes

I believe I understand how HADOOP knows that a node has crashed. If the cluster manager does not receive a heart beat from one of the slaves in a predetermined amount of time, then it figures it is dead.

How does the cluster manager determine if a node is slow ? Once it determines the node is slow, what does it do with the tasks on that node ?

Thanks.

Comment: I don’t believe that YARN is aware that a node is slow. YARN just distributes the jobs across all nodes with available resources and the slow node will take more time to complete its job and get less available resources to process additional jobs. Ultimately YARN may kill a job that takes too much time on this server and reassign it.

Comment: You may be right Harold, that is YARN does not have mechanisms to deal with slow nodes. However, you also mention that ultimately, YARN will kill a job if it is too slow. So it does have someway of determining a job is too slow ? Thanks for your response and I will also keep looking to get a definitive answer and update this post.

Comment: Actually the long job would be killed by the Application Master (example: a Spark Driver) not by YARN which is a just ressource manager.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. I am using the the following reference "[Hadoop: The Definitive Guide](http://hadoopbook.com/)" by Tom White.

Harold is correct. As per the book, the Tasks launched by an application reports status to the application master at a regular interval. If the application master finds that a task is not reporting progress, it assumes the task is hanging and automatically kills the corresponding JVM. The default timeout period is mentioned as 10 min.

What constitutes progress is a separate discussion also included in the book.